# Navigate to a certain paragraph number

Tags: navigation, paragraphs

How can I navigate to a certain paragraph number?

If I want to move to the 33rd *line* in a file, I execute `M-x goto-line <RET> 33`, but there does not seem to be an equivalent `goto-paragraph` function.

I could write a function to do this for me (i.e. go to beginning of file, then execute `forward-paragraph` X number of times), but I am wondering if there is a built-in function for this already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of a built-in function for this, but as you already noted you can write one:

```
(defun goto-paragraph (arg)
  "Go to paragraph ARG."
  (interactive "nGoto paragraph: ")
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (forward-paragraph arg))
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a way to launch emacs and have it automatically navigate to a paragraph in the passed file, like you can do with line numbers? For example, I can do `emacs +33 file.txt` to open `file.txt` at line 33. Could I do this for paragraph 33?

Comment: I think so, but that is quite a bit more complicated and probably worth its own question! The short answer is that there is support for processing your own command-line options during Emacs startup. You might also be able to use `--funcall` or `--eval`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you were already aware of this or not, but you can interactively do this without writing a function per se, using the universal argument -- in my emacs `forward-paragraph` is bound to `"M-}"`, so you can go to beginning of buffer, `"C-u-33-M-}"` and it will jump forward 33 paragraphs. You could even capture this to a keyboard macro with a `kbd-macro-query` inside to ask you how many paragraphs, and then save that macro off and bind it to a key. Just to let you know that there are ways to do this without writing any Emacs Lisp at all.

Comment: FWIW you can also just do (say) M-33 M-} to avoid that awkward C-u...